# How to use EXPECT in a loop for ssh

Tags: shell-script, sftp, expect

Our Linux setup doesn't have keygen configured for passwordless authentication. Hence I am supposed to use only `EXPECT` for passwordless authentication in a shell script.

```
   /usr/bin/expect<<EOF >> ${LOG_FILE}

set timeout 60
spawn   sftp ${EWS_USER}@${EWS_HOST}:${TGT_DIR}
expect "*?assword:"
send "$password\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put $local_dir/$line\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
expect EOF
EOF

        filename=$(basename "$line")
        # echo "File Name: $filename"
        #Calculate the MD5Sum locally.
        local_md5sum=$(md5sum "$line")
        #echo "Local MD5Sum: ${local_md5sum}"
        #Calculate the MD5sum in remote machine
        remote_md5sum=$(ssh ${EWS_USER}@${EWS_HOST} "cd '$TGT_DIR' ; find -name '$filename'  -exec md5sum {} \;" < /dev/null)
        #echo "Remote MD5Sum: ${remote_md5sum}"

LOCAL_SUM=`echo ${local_md5sum} | awk {'print $1'}`
REMOTE_SUM=`echo ${remote_md5sum} | awk {'print $1'}`
echo $LOCAL_SUM
echo $REMOTE_SUM
if [ "${LOCAL_SUM}" != "${REMOTE_SUM}" ]
then
        echo "SFTP Successfull"
else
        echo "SFTP Unsuccessfull"
fi
```

I know how to use `EXPECT` in the following scenario:

```
sftp ${EWS_USER}@${EWS_HOST} << EOF >> ${LOG_NAME}
put ${LOCAL_DIR}/${line} ${TGT_DIR}/${line}
EOF
```

But any idea how to use EXPECT here in the scenario below to make the connection passwordless?

```
remote_md5sum=$(ssh ${EWS_USER}@${EWS_HOST} "cd '$TGT_DIR' ; find -name '$filename'  -exec md5sum {} \;" < /dev/null)
```

Comment: Typically in `expect` via `spawn ssh ssh-args-here` and then suitable statements to match and respond to the password prompt.

Comment: Have you tried sshpass software? It might be easier to use it in this example.

Comment: I cant use SSHPASS. I am expected to make it work with EXPECT @Kalavan

Comment: @thrig I know how to use EXPECT normally for SFTP. But I am confused of how to use EXPECT for the below line.
`remote_md5sum=$(ssh ${EWS_USER}@${EWS_HOST} "cd '$TGT_DIR' ; find -name '$filename'  -exec md5sum {} \;" < /dev/null`
Could you please elaborate how to use EXPECT in the above line?

Comment: What have you written for `expect`? All I see is shell code, not `expect`.

Comment: Have a look at Ansible.

Comment: @sabarish Expanding on @thrig's notes, you mention Expect so we "expect" that you have tried to write an expect script already. In your question, you showed your code for sftp, but it is a regular `sh` script with `HERE` documents  to control sftp from the shell, and you did not use Expect. You even used awk within your script, which would not be necessary in an Expect script. Your true answer is briefly stated in @thrig's first answer.

Comment: @thrig @cardiff I have altered my `SFTP`  part to use EXPECT. That is working fine. But how do I use the same method in a single line for 
`$(ssh ${EWS_USER}@${EWS_HOST} "cd '$TGT_DIR' ; find -name '$filename' -exec md5sum {} \;" < /dev/null`
PLease help me on this.

Comment: If you need to use `expect` to provide a password then by definition it can't be passwordless authentication

Answer (score 0):

`expect` would be used for `ssh` in precisely the same way as for `sftp`, with the most complicated bit being how to extract the checksum from the output. This might run something along the lines of

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
#
# remote host sftp and then checksum a file. assumes linux coreutils
# available on both ends

if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
    puts stderr "Usage: $argv0 somefiletoxfer"
    exit 64
}

set local_file [lindex $argv 0]
set local_sum [lindex [split [exec md5sum $local_file] " "] 0]
set file_basename [lindex [split $local_file "/"] end]

set match_max 9999    ;# in the event of much output spam from sftp or ssh
set timeout 60

# these could also be read from $argv
set EWS_USER todofixme
set EWS_HOST todofixme
set TGT_DIR todofixme

set password hunter2

spawn sftp ${EWS_USER}@${EWS_HOST}:${TGT_DIR}
expect -ex "assword:"
send "$password\r"
expect -ex "sftp>"
send "put $local_file\r"
expect -ex "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
expect EOF

spawn ssh ${EWS_USER}@${EWS_HOST}
expect -ex "assword:"
send "$password\r"
send "md5sum ${TGT_DIR}/$file_basename\r"
expect -re {md5sum [^\n]+\n([A-Za-z0-9=_-]+) }
set remote_sum $expect_out(1,string)
send "exit\r"
expect EOF

if {$local_sum ne $remote_sum} {
    puts stderr "a failure prompts this dispatch" 
    puts stderr "for thy checksums do mismatch"
    puts stderr "local  >$local_sum<"
    puts stderr "remote >$remote_sum<"
    exit 1
}

puts $remote_sum
exit 0
```